# How to force task execution order in gradle 6.7.1

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am making a gradle script that must execute tasks in a specific order.

Despite looking that [this forum post](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-inject-tasks-between-test-and-build-task/5165) and [this documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:ordering_tasks), I do not understand how I am supposed to force task execution order.

I have this very complicated script:

```
task copyProjectTemplate(type: Copy) {
    doLast {
        println("copoying")
    }
    // from project_template_path_internal
    // into project_path
}

task createProject {
    mustRunAfter copyProjectTemplate
    doLast {
        println("project has been created")
    }
}
```

When executed with `gradle -b create_project.gradle createProject`, only the createProject task is executed.

Using the following alternative has the same behaviour:

```
task copyProjectTemplate(type: Copy) {
    doLast {
        println("copoying")
    }
    // from project_template_path_internal
    // into project_path
}

task createProject {
    doLast {
        println("project has been created")
    }
}

createProject.mustRunAfter copyProjectTemplate
```

The output in both cases is:

```
$ gradle -b create_project.gradle createProject

> Task :createProject   
project has been created

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

How can I force task execution order ?

---

Edit 1:

Using the documentation sample, I realise that the `Copy` type seems to "break" (or not work as I expect it) things.

For example:

```
task createProject {
    doLast {
        println 'createProject'
    }
}
task copyTemplate() {
    doLast {
        println 'copyTemplate'
    }
}
task taskZ {
    doLast {
        println 'taskZ'
    }
}
createProject.dependsOn copyTemplate
copyTemplate.dependsOn taskZ

>gradle -b create_project.gradle createProject
```

Executes the task in order:

```
$ gradle -b create_project.gradle createProject

> Task :taskZ
taskZ

> Task :copyTemplate
copyTemplate

> Task :createProject
createProject

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
```

But:

```
task createProject {
    doLast {
        println 'createProject'
    }
}
task copyTemplate(type: Copy) {
    doLast {
        println 'copyTemplate'
    }
}
task taskZ {
    doLast {
        println 'taskZ'
    }
}
createProject.dependsOn copyTemplate
copyTemplate.dependsOn taskZ

>gradle -b create_project.gradle createProject
```

Does not execute `copyTemplate`:

```
$ gradle -b create_project.gradle createProject

> Task :taskZ
taskZ

> Task :createProject
createProject

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
```

Why is that ?

Edit 2:

With actual copy commands (`from into`), the task is executed "correctly":

```
task createProject {
    doLast {
        println 'createProject'
    }
}
task copyTemplate(type: Copy) {
    doFirst {
        println "first copy ?"
    }
    doLast {
        println 'last copy ?'
    }
    from "./README.md"
    into "./yolo_project/"
}
task taskZ {
    doLast {
        println 'taskZ'
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ gradle -b create_project.gradle createProject

> Task :taskZ
taskZ

> Task :copyTemplate
first copy ?        
last copy ?

> Task :createProject
createProject

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
```

Could someone explain me why in "non copy typed" tasks, `doLast` and `doFirst` are considered as actions (or at least are actually printed) but not for the "copy typed" task, that seems to need the `from` and `into` instructios ?

Comment: If the copy task is configured to do nothing (IE, not configured),  it isn't executed